# How to test localized string on simulator?

Tags: iphone

I am using NSLocalizedString(); function for my localized strings. Even though i change my preferred language in simulator settings my string still get shown up in English.

Can we test the NSLocalizedString(); from simulator? if so how?

Can any one guide me through this please?

--
Regards,

U'suf

Answer (score 15):

To answer how to test localized string on simulator?

I will assume that you have successfully added the **Localizable.strings** files for various languages you and you app want to target.

Step 1 - Goto target in the run destination.

[image]

Step 2 - Expand the menu to show options and then click on **"Edit Scheme"**

[image]

Step 3 - Click on **"Run"** and then select **"Options"**. Choose the language you want to test for in the drop down available in the **"Application Language"**

[image]

Step 4 - **CMD + R**

That should be it!!

Please note that if you choose a language for which no Localization.string file was provided then it will show development language, which is more or less English.

Another but tedious way is to go to Simulator Settings > General > Language & Region > iPhone Language and choose the language. Since simulators can be buggy (like mine is) this process can be time consuming. Most of the time requiring rebooting of simulator (yet another time consuming task) for the changes to reflect.

Hope it helps!

Code and Prosper

Edit : [Official Apple Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html). If anyone is looking. Pointer -> **"Testing Specific Languages and Regions"**

Comment: Give this man a raise and approve his answer! It saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

The simulator can get stuck displaying the 'first' language if you have tested the app before it had a second localization.

The solution (XCode 4.5.2, iOS6) appears to be to delete the app from the simular then reinstall. After that you can change the language repeatedly and the localizations will appear in the simulator correctly.

Answer (score -3):

You should prepare localized strings for another languages.