# How does iOS perform localization in Cordova / Phonegap build?

Tags: ios, cordova, localization, phonegap

I am trying to display my app name in different languages.

1. English
2. Chinese (Simplified)
3. Chinese (Traditional)

I am using phonegap build to build the app so cannot use xcode.

Therefore, I have created 3 folders which contain respective InfoPlist.strings file manually on res folder like:

- en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
- zh.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
- zh-hant.lproj/InfoPlist.strings

Example of InfoPlist.strings file inside zh-hant.lproj folder:

[image]

My config.xml has these lines to copy to respective folder and also use it respectively.

```
        <resource-file src="res/zh-hant.lproj" target="zh-hant.lproj" />
        <resource-file src="res/zh.lproj" target="zh.lproj" />
        <resource-file src="res/en.lproj" target="en.lproj" />

        <!-- copy localization file -->

        <resource-file src="res/zh-hant.lproj/InfoPlist.strings" target="zh-hant.lproj/InfoPlist.strings" />
        <resource-file src="res/zh.lproj/InfoPlist.strings" target="zh.lproj/InfoPlist.strings" />
        <resource-file src="res/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings" target="en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings" />

        <config-file platform="ios" parent="LSHasLocalizedDisplayName" mode="replace">
        <true />
        </config-file>

        <edit-config target="CFBundleLocalizations" file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite">
            <array>
                <string>en</string> <!-- english -->
                <string>zh</string> <!-- chinese (simplified) -->
                <string>zh-hant</string> <!-- chinese (traditional) -->
            </array>
        </edit-config>
```

The problem is that when I install the app on iPhone the translation is not working. My current language set to English, I get the English name.

When I change language to chinese it does not reflect (translation not working, i.e still in English).

How do I fix this ? Is there anything I am missing ?

Comment: did you set this app names in App Store?

Comment: @Lu_ No I am just building and testing it locally right now. The app is not yet submitted to store.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to debug localisation, you need to edit your scheme, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261194/how-to-test-localized-string-on-simulator).

Comment: Hi NIkitah, thanks for your respsonse but I am using phonegap and I cannot debug the app.

Comment: A Phonegap build is just native app that uses the WebView component to display content. Your project is still an XCode project.

Comment: yes, but there is nothing to debug. I only have the locale files and may be iOS should just use it during the build, but you see it is not happening the correct way. May be I miss something.